# How to play audio directly in Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine

This really shouldn't be that difficult, but I cant seem to get a sound to play in a script.

```c#
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class State1 : State {
    AudioClip clip = new AudioClip();

    public override void initialize(){
        Debug.Log ("StateRemoveBolts.initialize()");
        clip = Resources.Load<AudioClip>("Sounds/my_sound");
        AudioSource.PlayClipAtPoint (clip, Vector3(0));
    }
    public override void destroy(){}
    public override void update(StateMachine sm){}
}
```

I get this error:

> error CS0119: Expression denotes a `type', where a`variable', `value' or`method group' was expected

Comment: Which line is the error on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Vector3(0)` is not valid code.

You either want:

- `Vector3.Zero` for a reference to the zero-vector (like doing `Math.PI`)

Or

- `new Vector3(0,0,0)` to create one

Comment: Vector3(0,0,0) has the same error. The error occurs on the line AudioSource.playclipatpoint() I can make the code work by doing a getComponent<audiosource> but it’s supposed to work without doing that in the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

As Draco said, `Vector3(0)` is not valid, nor is `Vector3(0, 0, 0)`.
What you want, is to use the `new` keyword, as otherwise, Unity thinks you are trying to feed it a variable type when it expects an actual variable, or value.

If you take out the `(0)`, you will get the same error, so what you put in the parenthesis is irrelevant, you need to use the `new` keyword too, which tells the compiler to call the Vector3 constructor.

Since it looks like you want all zeros, I would do `Vector3.Zero`.